# T-SQL While Infinite Loop

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The goal of the below script is to delete all records in a table for all the distinct users on it except the two first records for each user.

The thing is that the script goes into an infinite loop between these two lines

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
SET @Event = 0;
```

The complete script is

```
DECLARE @Event int, @User int;

DECLARE cUsers CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FOR SELECT DISTINCT(UserID) FROM Identifications;

OPEN cUsers

FETCH NEXT FROM cUsers INTO @User;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
SET @Event = 0;

BEGIN
    DECLARE cRows CURSOR STATIC LOCAL FOR
    SELECT EventIdentificacionId FROM Identifications WHERE UserId = @User AND EventIdentificacionId NOT IN
     (SELECT TOP 2 EventIdentificacionId FROM Identifications WHERE UserId = @User ORDER BY EventIdentificacionId);

    OPEN cRows
    FETCH NEXT FROM cRows INTO @Event;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      DELETE FROM Identifications WHERE EventIdentificacionId = @Event;
      FETCH NEXT FROM cRows INTO @Event;
    END

    CLOSE cRows;
    DEALLOCATE cRows;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cUsers INTO @User;
END

CLOSE cUsers;
DEALLOCATE cUsers;
```

Can anybody give me some solution/explanation please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, There are far better ways to do such a thing than using a cursor, let alone a couple of nested cursors.

One such better option is to use a common table expression and row_number, and then delete the rows directly from the common table expression.
I'm not entirely sure this code is correct because I have no real way to test it as you didn't provide sample data or desired results, but I came up with that based on the code in the question:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  UserId, 
            EventIdentificacionId,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY EventIdentificacionId) As Rn
    FROM Identifications
)

DELETE 
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn > 2 -- Delete all but the first two rows
```

Comment: Glad to help :-) T-SQL is very well documented, you should start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2):

Change this line as shown:

```
DECLARE @Event int = 0, @User int = 0;
```

And remove this line

```
SET @Event = 0;
```

The reason you have an infinite loop is that this code:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
SET @Event = 0;
BEGIN
```

Is actually this:

```
-- A loop of a single instruction, with no exit criteria
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 SET @Event = 0;

-- begin a new code block, with no condition or loop
BEGIN
```